# In Isabelle, what do the angle brackets and double asterisks mean?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving, formal-verification, isar

I'm trying to understand [some Isabelle code](https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle/blob/master/example/SimpleWallet.thy), and there is some syntax I don't understand. I haven't seen them in tutorials, including the two bundled with the Isabelle2017 distribution, "Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL" and "The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual". The fact that they're symbols, combined with Isabelle's very small user base, means that the answer is pretty un-google-able.

The first is tall angle brackets `⟨` `⟩`, and the second is a double asterisk `**` which renders in the output console as `∧*` (which is notably different than ASCII `^`).

Here's an [example](https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle/blob/master/example/SimpleWallet.thy#L116);

```
lemma pre_fifth_pure [simp]:
  "triple net failures (a ** b ** c ** d ** ⟨ P ⟩) cod post =
   (P ⟶ triple net failures (a ** b ** c ** d) cod post)"
```

The angle brackets always seem to surround a proposition. The definition of the `triple` function implies that `(a ** b ** c ** d)` is of type `state_element set ⇒ bool`, where a `state_element` is just a conjunction of a bunch of constructors;

```
datatype state_element =
    StackHeightElm "nat"
  | StackElm "nat * w256" ... (* 20 lines like this *)
```

Are these two pieces of syntax related? How could `(a ** b ** c ** d)` be a function? Why can it have different numbers of the things delimited by the stars? Is this somehow custom defined syntax? The mysteries abound.

Comment: Is this separation logic or something? Then maybe `**` is library-specific notation for “separating conjunction”, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_logic

Comment: If you open the definitions in Isabelle/jEdit, you can press Ctrl and click on syntax to see where it is comming from. In your example `**`seems to be special syntax defined for `sep_conj` in https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle/blob/master/sep_algebra/Separation_Algebra.thy .

There, you also find an abbreviation ``pred_K :: "'b ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'b" ("⟨⟨_⟩⟩") where
  "⟨⟨f⟩⟩ ≡ λs. f"``. Are these the brackets you ran into?

Comment: Nice! Do you want to write that up as an answer? @BenKeks I was looking at single angle brackets, which I eventually found defined here https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle/blob/master/Hoare/Hoare.thy#L257 althought I couldn't get the control-click to work for that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isabelle comes with rich mechanisms to define own notation. Therefore, it is quite common to run into unfamiliar syntax when one inspects theories written by others.

Using **Isabelle/jEdit**, you can press *Ctrl* (*Cmd* for Mac) and click on syntax and names to jump to their definition sites (cf. 3.5 of the [Isabelle/jEdit Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/doc/jedit.pdf)).

There are sporadic [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681578/syntax-that-works-with-ctrl-click-in-isabelle-jedit) where this might not work. Then, you can try typing `print_syntax` into your theory text, which will output all rules of the current inner syntax configuration (cf. 8.4.4 of [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2017/doc/isar-ref.pdf)). Hopefully, you can at least figure out which theory some notation is from by this. One should assume that benevolent theory authors would refrain from grammar setups that break the hyperlink feature.

For the specific problem here, `**` is syntactic sugar for `sep_conj` in https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle/blob/master/sep_algebra/Separation_Algebra.thy#L108 and `⟨ _ ⟩` is sugar for `pure` from https://github.com/pirapira/eth-isabelle/blob/master/Hoare/Hoare.thy#L257, as [Alex found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451860/in-isabelle-what-do-the-angle-brackets-and-double-asterisks-mean?noredirect=1#comment89939431_51451860).